# Fixing the height of "character boxes" in PDFs

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a software that can fix the height of "character boxes" in PDF.

Example:

[image]

when the string `p = 0.05` is selected, I don't want the selected area to have such a height when opened in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Any OS, license and price is fine.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in the screenshot above? I want to take a look at it before making a recommendation.

Comment: @MihaiIancu sure https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4y6Mj_UZoTEbm1nV1pIRTVER2M/view?usp=sharing page 4

Comment: The font used for p=0.05 text is a Type3 font and indeed by modifying the /FontBBox entry the selection works ok. The simplest solution is to perform a brute search/replace of "/FontBBox [0  0  1000  1000  ]" with "/FontBBox [0  0  100   100   ]" (the 2 strings must have exactly the same length). Before search/replace you have to save your file as PDF 1.4 to make sure all font structures are not compressed (in your file they are compressed).